# Regex for Password must contain 8 characters, 2 letter both lower or uppercase letters and one special character ' * ' 5 digit number

Tags: regex

I want to create an expression for password as below:

*Regex for passwords that must contain 8 characters, start with 2 lower or uppercase letters, contain one special character `*` and a 5-digit number.*

E.g.: `az*12345`

- It must be start with 2 characters;
- Contain only single `*`;
- End with 5 digits.

I have tried it with this pattern:
`(?=(.*[^a-zA-Z]){2})(?=.*[*]{1})(?=(.*\d){5}).{8}$`

However, it yields almost the same results as a regex above. It starts with any character but I want the exact above mentioned pattern. I know I am close to it. Please suggest me what I should do.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/fH8jW4/2?

Comment: Must the special character be the asterisk (*)? Wouldn't `^[a-zA-Z]{2}\*\d{5}$` be sufficient then?

Comment: If you don't want it to start with any character, don't make it start with `.*`. That means any character zero or more times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to match just `[2-letters]+[*]+[5-digits]` pattern, here is what you are looking for:

[`^[a-zA-Z]{2}\*[0-9]{5}$`](https://regex101.com/r/xJ4aE7/3).